# Tying to replace a file content with the machine current IP address

Tags: bash, pipe

I have a yaml config file(cli.yaml). with structure

```
database:
  host: "IP"
```

Now, I just want to replace the file content, Or more precisely THE `IP` string with my PC's current `IPV4` address.

As I am not very good with terminals, I  divided my work into several parts -

Like: For getting the IP: `ipconfig getifaddr en0` - Let's say the IP is - `10.0.0.1`
Now We know that `AWK` could help us to replace file content with `regrex`.

So, I tried to pipe both commands, Like: `ipconfig getifaddr en0 | awk '{print $1}'` And It worked. Print `10.0.0.1`

And finally: `ipconfig getifaddr en0 | awk '{sub(/IP/,$1)}1' cli.yaml > temp.txt && mv temp.txt cli.yaml`

But the output I am getting is:

```
database:
  host: "host:"
```

Which is not my expectation. Now, I figured, there is something wrong with `PIPE`. So I replace the `$1` with `$0`. But, Still not the expected output.

Any hints, anyone? What I am doing wrong!!

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using the [yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) wrapper for `jq` to update the value:

```
$ yq -Y --arg ip '10.0.0.1' '.database.host |= $ARGS.named.ip' cli.yaml
database:
  host: "10.0.0.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, but it is a bit the other way round. I am using the `REGEX` instead of the `IP` string.

```
awk -v ip="$(ipconfig getifaddr en0)" \
  '{sub(/((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)/,ip)}1' \
  ./config/cli.yaml > temp.txt && mv temp.txt ./config/cli.yaml
```